# Is an HBITMAP loaded in my process memory?

Tags: c, winapi, gdi

I have used the following code to load a 7.5 MB bitmap:

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    HBITMAP hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, "D:\\1.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
    Sleep(INFINITE);

    return 0;
}
```

However, when looking at the memory size that my process takes after loading the bitmap, it is less than 1 MB!

[image]

Can someone explain how loading a bitmap works in term of memory size.

Comment: Documentation [suggests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648045%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that promptly deleting a loaded bitmap helps decreasing the size of the process's working set. So that is where it goes. Maybe the call was optimized out? Maybe the task manager is not telling the truth? Maybe the function in fact failed to load the file?

Comment: The words after "Memory" are important.  I'd guess its says (private working set).  You don't pay for a bitmap until you actually start using it.   The wonders of a demand-paged virtual memory operating system.  Use View > Select Columns and tick Commit size to see a blip.